# Excel formatting for large data

Tags: excel

I have a list of family members containing the name of a person and his/her sibs. The data (PIC1) show some repetition which I want to avoid i.e. the data is showing sibs of ammad in columns B and then one of these sibs is taken in the column A and other sibs (including ammad, this time) in B and so on. But what I want is only name of one member (in column A) and the sibs (in column B) ONLY and ONLY once. The final data must look like the PIC2.

[image: PIC1]

[[image: PIC22]

Comment: Post few sample data then desired output. Did you try any formula?

Comment: Sample is provided now

Comment: Give a try on `=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$B1,B1)=1,A1:B1,"")`.

Comment: How can you be sure « ammad akbar » is a duplicate of « akbar ammad » and not a separate person? Mr David David is a valid name and the name serves as first and family…

Comment: @Harun24hr, Nope. Not working for me. Have you done it by yourself?

Comment: So you need to check *groups* of data. In Pic 1 the first group is `ammad, ali, akbar, maria` and the third group is `akbar, ammar, ali, maria`. Same members but different order. I don't know any single way to get this with formulas. You'll need to code something in VBA for sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain your desired output using `Power Query`, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365 Excel

- Select some cell in your original table
- `Data => Get&Transform => From Table/Range` or `From within sheet`
- When the PQ UI opens, navigate to `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table Name in Line 2 of the code.
- Replace the existing code with the **M-Code** below
- Change the table name in line 2 of the pasted code to your "real" table name
- Examine any comments, and also the `Applied Steps` window, to better understand the algorithm and steps

**M Code**

```
let

//change next line to reflect your actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table7"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}}),

//fill down Column 1
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Changed Type",{"Column1"}),

//group by column 1
//then aggregate each group by a sorted, case-insensitive list of names
//   and remove the duplicates
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filled Down", {"Column1"}, {
        {"x", each 
            Table.Sort(
                Table.Distinct(
                    Table.RemoveColumns(
                        Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(_,{},"Attribute","Sibs"),
                    "Attribute"),Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase), 
            {"Sibs",Order.Ascending})}
        }),

//Remove duplicate tables
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Grouped Rows", {"x", Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase}),

//Filter each subtable to remove the name in column1
//then remove the now unneeded column of subtables
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Duplicates", "Custom", each Table.SelectRows([x], (t)=>t[Sibs]<>[Column1]), type table),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"x"}),

//expand the subtables and set the data types
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Custom", {"Sibs"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Custom",{{"Sibs", type text}}),

//Null the appropriate names in Column1
    col1 = #"Changed Type1"[Column1],
    nullSome = List.Generate(
        ()=>[x=col1{0}, idx = 0],
        each [idx] < List.Count(col1),
        each [x=if col1{[idx]+1}= col1{[idx]} then null else col1{[idx]+1}, idx = [idx]+1],
        each [x]),

//create results table
    results = Table.FromColumns(
        {nullSome} & {#"Changed Type1"[Sibs]},
        type table[Member=text, Sibs=text])
in
    results
```

[image]